# Google developers console cloud storage bucket or file delete buttons permanently disabled

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I've been looking at Google Cloud Storage. I upload files in my Java program by calling BlobstoreService.createUploadUrl with UploadOptions specifying the default bucket name for the cloud project.
The files appear in the console under the default cloud storage bucket, but the delete button is always disabled. Obviously I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23900943/remove-all-files-under-a-folder-google-cloud-storage)

The files delete with gsutil, no billing enable required.

The disabled buttons referred to in the question are not consistent with [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Default_Gcs_Bucket) which says:

"Each app can have a default Google Cloud Storage (GCS) bucket that is ready to use with no further activations, configurations, or permission settings required."

Or [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage#Using_the_Default_GCS_Bucket) which states:

"The bucket is simply there and ready to use, with a free quota. You do not need to make your app billable if you use this option.

Looks like the disabling is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the billing to delete file on GCS. When you will enable billing, delete button will be enable.
Hope I can help you..

Comment: I agree it seems billing must be enabled to access the default GCS bucket via Dev Console. It's stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/faq#gettingstarted) billing must be turned on to use GCS. Both these points seem inconsistent with the links provided in timmacp's answer. I assumed a "default" GCS bucket would not be fundamentally different from other types of buckets, and that the main difference would involve billing and quota settings. But this suggests the "default" GCS bucket associated with an App is _categorically_ different in usage (e.g., no dev console interactions?).

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way that the buttons are not disabled. Using the storage browser from the regular project console the address is:

https://console.developers.google.com/project/projectname/storage/browser/projectid.appspot.com/?authuser=0

The buttons are disabled at that address. But this one seems to have the buttons working fine:

https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/projectid.appspot.com/

Comment: Apparently this is the easiest workaround. Should be the accepted answer