# Can I trigger a Firebase cloud function based on new uploads to a specific folder in Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

[From Firebase Storage DOCS:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions)

> **Trigger a function on Cloud Storage changes**
>
> Use functions.storage to create a function that handles Cloud Storage events. Depending on whether you want to scope your function to a specific Cloud Storage bucket or use the default bucket, use one of the following:
>
> - `functions.storage.object()` to listen for object changes on the default storage bucket.
> - `functions.storage.bucket('bucketName').object()` to listen for object changes on a specific bucket.

**QUESTION**

Can I listen for changes inside a specific folder of my bucket?

**Example:**

`//myBucket/blog-post-images/...`

Only trigger for files uploaded to the `blog-post-images` folder?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Have a look at this answer from Doug Stevenson (Firebase team) which explains that "there are not actually any "folders" in Cloud Storage. There are just object names that look like they contain folders."   https://stackoverflow.com/a/56179173/3371862

Comment: Makes sense! It's probably not possible. Thanks

Comment: PS: note that you could deduce the folder from the object name, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions#access_storage_object_attributes

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll have to do that.